# How to get value from DB for specific date?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a database table which have field counter that counts number of requests to API (by updating it +1), but I want to get these counts for specific date, (for this month). Is it possible to get it? I am using PostgreSQL.

**SQL query**

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Admin (
        id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
        counter INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
        created_date TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT Now()
        );
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you want counts by month's ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Group query results by month and year in postgresql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17492167/group-query-results-by-month-and-year-in-postgresql)

Comment: are you keeping the update transactions in any other table?

Comment: @Sund'er no I am just updating existing field counter

Comment: @droebi No, I have only created date, and I update existing counter

Comment: Better revisit your table design and insert a row for every API request (time-series approach). Counter will then be an aggregate.

Comment: postgres is not keeping history for the tables DML's. so create a trigger for every update .

Comment: @Sund'er can you show how should it be pls?

Comment: @Stefanov.sm sorry I didn't get what you meant

Comment: @mirodil then I recommend to redesign your table: log your requests by id and timestamp and get your statistics by select (count by month)

Comment: I mean exactly what @droebi just said. But you can count for any period of time, not just month

Answer (score 1):

you can use subquery in two cases:

**1- If with each request a field is saved in the database, then you will need the number of all fields per month**:

> **count(counter) -> number of all fields per month.**

> **EXTRACT(MONTH FROM created_date ) = EXTRACT(MONTH FROM Now()) -> date in this month**

Query :

```
select count(counter) as "counter In This month"
     from Admin 
         where created_date in( select created_date from Admin where EXTRACT(MONTH FROM created_date ) = EXTRACT(MONTH FROM Now()));
```

**2- If you update the counter after each request, so that the counter in one day equals the number of all requests on the same day.**

> **sum(counter) -> Total number of all requests per month**

> **EXTRACT(MONTH FROM created_date ) = EXTRACT(MONTH FROM Now()) -> date in this month.**

Query :

```
select sum(counter) as "counter In This month"
     from Admin 
         where created_date in( select created_date from Admin where EXTRACT(MONTH FROM created_date ) = EXTRACT(MONTH FROM Now()));
```

Comment: Simply `where date_trunc('month', created_date) = date_trunc('month', current_date)`

Comment: @Stefanov.sm Yes, you can too, I'm a beginner in postgresql, thanks for noticing

Comment: This is bad approach

Comment: @SlavaRozhnev Can you advise me of certain things that can help me in improving the query?

Comment: @OmarHussien, sure! Just ask question and many volunteers will be happy to help you!

Comment: This answer was reviewed in the [Low Quality
Queue](https://stackoverflow.com/help/review-low-quality). Here are some
guidelines for How do [I write a good
answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Code only answers are
**not considered good answers**, and are likely to be downvoted and/or deleted
because they are less useful to a community of learners. Please [edit] your
answer to include an explanation of how and why the code solves the problem,
when it should be used, what its limitations are, and if possible a link to
relevant documentation.

Comment: @ljmc Thank you for your comments and I will amend the answer to make it more clear and useful

Comment: @OmarHussien How it works? In my case counter only is being updated not created everytime

Comment: @mirodil see case two

Comment: @OmarHussien thanks, I am going to use first case, but is it possible counting by its name if I save each request by name? like Api1 - 40, Api2 - 30, Api3 - 43....

Comment: @mirodil If you specify a specific label in each request-name that refers to the specific API, and you will need SQL query for each API, you can choose the number of requests provided that the request name is like the name of the API.

Comment: @OmarHussien These queries counts even if years are different, but it's not correct

Comment: @mirodil All you have to do is add another condition in the subquery, which is that the year must be the same as the requested year

Answer (score 0):

I would also recommend using `date_part` function:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(counter) 
   FROM Admin
   WHERE date_part('month', created_date) = date_part('month', current_date)
;
```

Comment: This query slow. Better to use where created_date between month_start and month_end

Comment: @Farhad How it works? In my case counter only is being updated not created everytime

Comment: What do you mean by that? If `counter` is only being updated, so there will be only one row for each API route in the DB. And that makes everything fuzzy, would you please explain to us how and when your data are being inserted in the table?