# Translate SQL to Polars and Pandas

Tags: python, sql, pandas

Can someone help me translate

```sql
SELECT (TRUNC(lat/0.5)*0.5) AS ll_lat, (TRUNC(lon/0.5)*0.5) AS ll_lon, COUNT(lat) AS  strikes FROM lightning GROUP BY ll_lat, ll_lon;
```

into Pandas and Polars code as I tried

```py
# Pandas
df['ll_lat'] = (df['lat'] // 0.1 * 0.1).round(1)
df['ll_lon'] = (df['lon'] // 0.1 * 0.1).round(1)
df['temporalBasket'] = df['eventtime'].astype(str).str[:13]
df = df.groupby(['ll_lat', 'll_lon', 'temporalBasket']).agg(strikes=('lat', 'count'))
# 3763740 rows × 1 columns
```

```py
# Polars
df_p_out = df_p.groupby(
    (pl.col("lat") // 0.1 * 0.1).alias("ll_lat"),
    (pl.col("lon") // 0.1 * 0.1).alias("ll_lon"),
    pl.col("eventtime").dt.truncate("1h").alias("temporalBasket"),
).agg(strikes=pl.col("lat").count())
# shape: (3763740, 4)
```

as opposed to the SQL shape (10168 rows × 3 columns). My Dataframe looks like this

[image]

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible example, it's currently hard to test anything. Also make sure that rounding is working as expected (you use `0.5` in SQL and `0.1` in python).

Comment: Don't group by `temporalBasket`. Try: `df = df.groupby(['ll_lat', 'll_lon']).agg(strikes=('lat', 'count'), event=('temporalBasket', 'first'))`

Comment: Your sql doesn't have the time element in it whereas your polars does. Either put temporalbasket in sql or take it out of your polars groupby

Comment: As an aside, wgs84 coordinates don't have fixed distances so grouping by rounding the coordinates is going to have bigger areas the closer you get to the equator. https://wiki.gis.com/wiki/index.php/Geodetic_system

Comment: @DeanMacGregor very good point sir, how would I translate the temporal Basket in SQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
df['ll_lat'] = (df['lat'] // 0.5 * 0.5).round(1)  # 0.5 or 0.1?
df['ll_lon'] = (df['lon'] // 0.5 * 0.5).round(1)  # 0.5 or 0.1?
df['temporalBasket'] = df['eventtime'].str[:13]   # YYYY-MM-DD HH

out = (df.groupby(['ll_lat', 'll_lon'], as_index=False)
         .agg(strikes=('lat', 'count'),
              event=('temporalBasket', 'first')))
```

While there are 1000 records in `df`, `out` has 857 rows after aggregation:

```
>>> out
     ll_lat  ll_lon  strikes          event
0     -46.0   -72.5        1  2022-09-12 23
1     -38.5   -58.0        1  2022-06-27 07
2     -38.0   -58.0        1  2022-04-20 03
3     -37.0   -72.5        1  2023-03-29 01
4     -35.0   -59.0        1  2023-01-23 12
..      ...     ...      ...            ...
852    63.5    11.0        1  2022-09-08 08
853    63.5    20.0        1  2022-04-24 03
854    64.5    21.0        1  2022-05-02 11
855    65.0   -14.0        1  2022-10-12 14
856    65.5    78.0        1  2023-03-07 11

[857 rows x 4 columns]

>>> df
           lat         lon            eventtime  ll_lat  ll_lon temporalBasket
0    45.804626   15.874926  2023-03-30 09:48:05    45.5    15.5  2023-03-30 09
1    34.674118  -92.351753  2022-06-13 22:18:29    34.5   -92.5  2022-06-13 22
2    50.614098    3.124432  2023-02-07 22:29:37    50.5     3.0  2023-02-07 22
3   -27.143572  -56.766484  2022-05-14 11:08:50   -27.5   -57.0  2022-05-14 11
4    43.503934   16.523779  2022-10-18 01:31:38    43.5    16.5  2022-10-18 01
..         ...         ...                  ...     ...     ...            ...
995  53.909600   37.736000  2022-12-15 13:45:56    53.5    37.5  2022-12-15 13
996  55.870995   -4.249439  2023-01-06 03:44:50    55.5    -4.5  2023-01-06 03
997   5.196440  -74.234923  2022-08-10 01:51:16     5.0   -74.5  2022-08-10 01
998  -6.509253  106.897496  2022-12-17 17:24:56    -7.0   106.5  2022-12-17 17
999  49.788203   19.705980  2022-08-24 15:03:58    49.5    19.5  2022-08-24 15

[1000 rows x 6 columns]
```

Comment: Weirdly enough (even after running with the typo fixed (it is 0.5) I do not get what the SQL gives me. I am not sure why would a similar query give me 620886 rows instead of the 10168 expected ones, unless my code is not well translated. How would I recreate the temporal basket in SQL to make them match?

Comment: Don't group by temporalBasket to check if you have the same output

Comment: I did get the same output sir, Any idea how to translate the `temporalBasket` into SQL?

Comment: Is `eventime` stored as VARCHAR or DATETIME?

Comment: In the PostgreSQL DB it is `text` and in the parquet file it is `datetime[ns]` Sir/Madame.

Comment: Maybe you can use `SUBSTRING` to extract the first 13 characters?

Comment: @Curious something like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17492167/group-query-results-by-month-and-year-in-postgresql

Comment: Yes but it seems your column is text so I don't think you can use `date_trunc` but the idea with `substring` is the same.